# sql string to get the maximum of the union of minimum values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables and I would like to have an sql query to get the minimum value of a field of the union of the maximums of the tables.

```
Set tmpRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(" SELECT MIN(s.TorqueMax) FROM ( " & _
    " (SELECT MAX(ds.TorqueMax) FROM tblUIOpTorqueRangeDS ds)" & _
    " UNION " & _
    " (SELECT MAX(cv.TorqueMax) FROM tblUIOpTorqueRangeCV cv )) as s")
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A single clear query would also help.

Comment: While you are [edit]ing in the sample data, format your code so it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(s.TorqueMax)
FROM (SELECT MAX(ds.TorqueMax) as TorqueMax
      FROM tblUIOpTorqueRangeDS ds
      UNION 
      SELECT MAX(cv.TorqueMax) as TorqueMax
      FROM tblUIOpTorqueRangeCV cv
     ) as s;
```

Comment: @AlbertLao-an ... Be sure to save this as an Access query object to cache best execution plan and not run it as a string query in VBA: `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mySavedQuery")`